# How to get the value of a field during the paste event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, copy-paste

I have a text field that I'm binding the `paste` event to using JQuery.  When I first paste something into the form field and log its `val()` it returns a blank string.  Likewise, if I paste again into the field, it returns the previous value *before* pasting.  Essentially I have a race condition or sequencing issue, for lack of a better term.  It seems the form field will not update until the paste event completes.

Is there any way to check the value of the field *after* the paste event has completed and the field is actually populated?  I want the actual field value, not the clipboardData, as I know that's an IE-only feature.

```
$('#url').bind('paste', function(e) {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: can't you use change event instead of paste?

Comment: @kender - Only if the OP wants to wait until the user moves the focus away from the input.

Comment: One important point: the `paste` event has existed in IE since version 5 but has only relatively recently made it into other browsers. Firefox 2, for example, doesn't have it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It turns out a decent solution is to wrap the callback in a `setTimeout()`, with a delay of 0 milliseconds, in order to make it asynchronous.

My new code is:

```
var urlField = $('#url');
urlField.bind('paste', function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert(urlField.val());
    }, 0); // note the 0 milliseconds
});
```

Thanks to [DigitalBush's Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/), it uses this technique throughout the source.

Comment: I'd like to mention that this works on any latent operations that rely on getting the value of the field.