# How to check if value of input is changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check if input was changed or not. Problem is - if i'll use this code:

```
trigger.keyup(function() {
    current_input = getSearchString();
    is_changed = (current_input != previous_input);
    previous_input = current_input;
});
```

This logic will break when user will press, for example "Q", after a short delay "E" (input value will be "QE" already) and release "Q" key first. `previous_input` will be set to "QE". User releases "E" key and script compares equal strings. So, when input actually did change, for my script it is not. Any idea how to fix this or is there any different way to do this (not with html5 event 'input')?

Comment: Would `keydown` help here?

Comment: `onchange` tells you when it changed.

Comment: onchange only fires when you lose focus

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `keydown` ***instead*** of `keyup`, that way you are **not** reliant on whether or not the user releases the keys.

Comment: Ah, i've got confused because this part is combined with other logic in my script. Yeah, that'll completely solve my problem, thanks :)

Comment: No problem @smsteel Happy to help! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Depending on key events alone is not a reliable mechanism. For example: what is user pastes text from the clipboard, or if he drags and drops text into the textbox (yes, dnd works for textboxes).

To account for all possible channels, you can use the `textchanged` event. Details here: http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event

```
$('#selector').bind('textchange', function (e, prevText) {
    // do your stuff here
});
```

Comment: Hmmmm then you can just listen to **both** `change` and `keydown`, no real need to add a plugin for it...

Comment: @Neal - Wrong! `change` won't fire for text inputs unless you press enter or lose focus.

Comment: Right! Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/7skY7/ :-) it shows what was pasted into the input :-) All without an extra plugin (Here is the reason for the timeout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055224/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-field-during-the-paste-event)

Comment: @Neal - `paste` solves it to a large extent, yes (wont work in opera &  older versions of safari - but will work on any decent new browser). Still it won't work if the user *drags and drops text* into the input.

Comment: I think the real comment here should be about `bind()` being used. jQuery team suggests we use .on for this in recent versions (actually for a while now)

Comment: @techfoobar all I needed to do was add the `drop` event: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/7skY7/ :-D

Comment: @Neal - Yeah, now with keydown, change, paste & drop it is a reliable method (for modern browsers). Important to note that drop event is rather new and was introduced only with HTML5.

Comment: Most desktop browsers use HTML5 in modern times @techfoobar :-)

Comment: @Neal Most clients/companies require you support IE8 or earlier. Sucks but it's how it goes.

Comment: @rlemon yea... It is annoying. I have made people in my office use Chrome :-P The advantage of being the only web-dev