# Are PASTE events asynchronous? What is the best way to handle this?

Tags: javascript, html, events, paste, onpaste

Recently, I noticed a strange behaviour of paste events: the value of an input element is updated **after** the function is triggered! If you just pass to the function the value itself or event.target.value, the function gets an old input value; the only workaround I found is to set a timeout and process `event.target.value` after some small random time when the input value is already updated. Is there perhaps some better solution (e.g., somethig like *event.oncomplete* that would allow to use the Promise API and resolve a promise after a paste operation is complete and the value of an input element is already updated?

Below is a runnable demo code snippet that shows the situation – if no timeout is set, the input element value is evaluated and changed by the function before pasting is complete:

```js
function alertValue({ target: t }) {
  const [run, delay] = [() => {
    alert(`The value is: "${t.value}".`);
    t.value = '';
  }, document.getElementById('sel').value];
  delay ? setTimeout(run, 10) : run();
}
```

```html
<h1>Paste event demo</h1>
<select id="sel">
  <option value="">Without timeout</option>
  <option value="1">WITH timeout</option>
</select><br>
<label>Paste something here:</label><br>
<input type="text" onpaste="alertValue(event)">
```

Comment: `onpaste` fires before the input's value is changed. `setTimeout` is how it is usually handled: [Javascript OnPaste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972954) and [How to get the value of a field during the paste event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055224)

Comment: As of now, all modern browsers support the clipboard events' `clipboardData` property, that lets you access the data on the clipboard that is about to be pasted.

Comment: `paste` works just like `keydown` - the event that *causes* some input

Comment: Yes, exactly. That is why I try to use not `onkeydown`, but `onkeyup` instead. Another good option is `oninput`; however with `oninput` it is impossible to track, e.g., when a user presses `enter` (because `input` events lack the `keyCode` property and also are not triggered on key presses that do not change input). So, in my project I use for updating values `onkeyup` + `onpaste`.

Comment: As for the function `event.clipboardData.getData("text")`, it works well without timeout. However, it should be noted that it returns only the value that is being pasted, not the new value of an input element. E.g.: the input element's value was initially "my value"; then you paste "SuPeR" somewhere in the middle, and the new value is "my SuPeRvalue"; in this case, event.clipboardData.getData("text")will return only "SuPeR". And if there's a need to get the updated input elemtnt's value — NOT the pasted value — `setTimeout` seems to be the only option, though.